# splitting a vector of letters into vectors of equal size

Tags: r, matrix, vector, fasta

I have some fasta sequence which is made out of hundreds of thousand of letters "a" "g" "c" "t"

```
library(seqinr)
mydata<-read.fasta(file="sequence.fasta")
mydata1<-mydata[[1]]
```

I would like cut it into vectors of equal lengths of let's say size 100. Manually it would look something like

```
vec1<-mydata1[c(1:100)]
vec2<-mydata1[c(101:200)]
```

etc. I do not have access to any other coding program hence it must be done in r. I am thinking about a for loop of some kind but I don't know how to implement one. Is this task even possible in r?

EDIT: This question is not the same as the one highlighted because I don't have a numeric vector but DNA sequence made out of letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we need to split by vectors of length 100

```
lst <- split(my.data, as.integer(gl(length(my.data), 100, length(my.data))))
```

Comment: When I type your command it ends up with a "+" sign and nothing happens. I don't quite understand?

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, it is because one of more closing bracket `)` is required.  Can you try it now

Comment: Thank you very much, works like a charm!